# What does <None Remove="..." /> mean in csproj?

Tags: .net-core, csproj

I'm working with a dotnet core csproj and I've added a new file. It doesn't initially get added to the csproj at all because of convention over configuration. But as soon as I change its Build Action from None to Embedded resource, two entries are written to the csproj file:

```
<None Remove="MyFile.sql" />
```

and

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="MyFile.sql" />
```

What does that first entry mean? It seems superfluous to me.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The sdk-style projects have a few automatic includes.

By default, the sdk has something like `<None Include="**/*">` (simplified) that is added (included) before your project's contents. But you don't want your file to be in the "None" set, but in the "EmbeddedResource" set.

MSBuild doesn't have any problem with the files being in more than one item group, but it should only be in one so IDEs don't get confused (and display the file only once an show the correct build action).

So the two statements mean "remove it from the None set (items) and add it to the EmbeddedResource set (items)".

Comment: I see no difference with or without the remove in my csproj - `<None Remove="testJson\**\*.json" />`, what should I expect to see? I'm using Rider as my IDE.

Comment: Fun fact: changing properties (with vs2019) on a file / folder in the project shows the editing done by the IDE when you have the corresponding csproj file opened by 'edit project file' . Switching from none to content or else shows some live action in the csproj file when opened in edit mode.

Comment: @Martin So what is suggested here? To keep both lines? What happens if you remove the first line?

Comment: For anyone wondering - I usually remove the None line to avoid the confusion.  Visual Studio '19 doesn't have a problem with it from what I can tell - a few months later

Comment: Visual Studio sure does have problems with these files being multiple groups and automatic behavior can lead to project breaks, it can get very confused, and start producing multiple copies on different paths, and also stop copying new versions.

Comment: It gets weird if you start setting metadata (e.g. CopyToOutputDirectory) and VS messes up which item now to modify. There's a good heuristic and some order but if it is wrong and there are issues with it, one might have a hard time figuring out the underlying issue.
I recommend to keep the Remove part to not end up with both IDE confusions or "duplicate item" errors (esp. when publishing)