# Error APT2144: Invalid file path obj/debug - deleting bin/obj folders does not resolve

Tags: maui

I am getting and error when trying to build my MAUI Android app

I have tried deleting the bin and obj folders and then doing a Clean and Rebuild many times as per other SO articles recommendations, but the errors do not go away:

```
Error   APT2144 invalid file path 
'C:\Folder\AndroidPatientAppMaui\obj\Debug\net8.0-android\res\resources\images\backicon.svg'.
AndroidPatientAppMaui   C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.43\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets 123
```

Note: I do see the csproj keeps adding these no matter what I do, even if I delete them and rebuild:

```
  <MauiImage Remove="Resources\Images\backicon.svg" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\backicon.svg" />
```

I get this error for about 10 files. What else can I do?

Comment: In which folder did you put the backicon.svg? `AndroidPatientAppMaui\obj\Debug\net8.0-android\res\resources\images` or `AndroidPatientAppMaui\Resources\Images`

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT  AndroidPatientAppMaui\Resources\Images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After added an image, the `<None Remove="xxx" />` would be added automatically in .csproj file. It means the image's Build Action changed from the `None` state. you can refer to the answer in [What does  mean in csproj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784191/what-does-none-remove-mean-in-csproj/49785443#49785443).

So you can first try to set the image's Build Action to `MauiImage`(Right click the image file -> Property - > Build Action). Then add the `update` property for image in csproj file like the following code:

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*"/>
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\donet_bot.svg" BaseSize="128,128"/>
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\backicon.svg"/>
```